# Why is my computed property asking for a setter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

In our code base there is a function:

```
    userCanUploadAttachment() {
        if (this.manualFileUploadIsActive) {
            if (!this.contact.attachment) {
                if (this.permission('canUploadAttachments')) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    },
```

There is only one place that the computed property is called, and that's in this bit:

```
     <b-button
       v-if="userCanUploadAttachment"
       class="btn-lg pull-right hide-when-printing"
       @click="uploadAttachment(contact.id)"
     >
```

That's the only two places in the whole file that `userCanUploadAttachment` is called. Why is it asking for a setter? The message:

`[Vue warn]: Computed property "userCanViewAttachment" was assigned to but it has no setter.`

Normally, that would be if you were setting it somewhere, but it's not being set anywhere?

Comment: Are you sure there is never a place where `userCanUploadAttachment` is set? Maybe from outside of the component? E.g. a quick search on `userCanUploadAttachment =`

Comment: Remember, it can also be set by Vue. Is there somehwere ```v-model``` is set to ```userCanUploadAttachment```?

Comment: No results found! Definitely not being set anywhere in the code

Comment: I changed the entire content of the computed function with "return true" and it still showed the error. I may just set up a setter and see what value is emitted.

Comment: Looks like it may be an issue with a Mixin, I'll see if I can fix it and report back

Comment: FYI function can be simplified to `return (this.manualFileUploadIsActive && !this.contact.attachment && this.permission('canUploadAttachments'));`

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderDeSousa, my next plan was to do this :)

Comment: You showing us the `userCanUploadAttachment` computed property but the error is on `userCanViewAttachment`.